# How can i set the SelectedIndex of a combobox inside a GridView inside a ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, combobox, binding

I have a Combobox inside a GridView (ListView). I want to set the SelectedIndex of the ComboBox with Code-behind. I tried via XAML with Binding the SelectedIndex but i get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException after adding my objects via LVCriteria.Items.Add(object). The value is 2 so inside the Index.

```
<ListView x:Name="LVCriteria" Width="500" Height="230" SelectionChanged="LVCriteria_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >                           
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Operator">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="CBOperator" SelectedIndex="{Binding Operator}"HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignComboBox}" Width="50"  Padding="0,0,0,5" SelectionChanged="CBOperator_SelectionChanged">
                            <ComboBoxItem Background="{StaticResource MaterialDesignPaper}" Content="&lt;"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Background="{StaticResource MaterialDesignPaper}" Content="&gt;"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Background="{StaticResource MaterialDesignPaper}" Content="="/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Background="{StaticResource MaterialDesignPaper}" Content="&lt;="/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Background="{StaticResource MaterialDesignPaper}" Content="&gt;="/>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The Class is

```
public class PK
{ 
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Criteria { get; set; }
    public float? Value { get; set; }
    public int Operator { get; set; }
    public int Comp_id { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Which error message do you get?

Comment: Thank You. I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException, but i checked my binding value and it is 2 so it is inside the ComboBox index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this work but the solution is a delay in the for-loop.
I use a for-loop for adding my objects into the ListView.

UPDATE: It is an Virtualization Problem. The solution is set

VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"

in the ListView.